# Eclipse doesn't generates R.java even without errors

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I just updated to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and installed Eclipse (via Ubuntu Software Center). I also installed the Android SDK and the plugin on Eclipse, however, I imported an old project (which was working correctly before) to it, and it don't even has generated R.java file.

In `gen/<my-package>` directory there is only a file named `BuildConfig.java`.

I tryied removing all the warnings from my xml files, and Build, Clean, etc, but it doesn't work.

I dont know if I'm missing some lib or what, because this project was being executed corrected on Eclipse before I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

**I tried creating a new project and check if it creates the R.java file, however, it wasn't created. Maybe the problem is with the eclipse.**

---

**UPDATE**

The same problem is happening to IntelliJ.

---

Please help me with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: try creating a new blank project and see if it creates and runs successfully. Every now and then I've had a project folder get broken for one reason or another and it will work if I create a new project and paste the source files from the other in to the new. If your new project works correctly I'd suggest going that route.

Comment: @Tim I just created a new project and it didnt generates the file automatically. It shows the same error, as if the R.java didnt exists.

Comment: what's the version number of your sdk and adt plugin?

Comment: @duanhong169 The ADT is 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 and the SDK is 15.

Comment: ADT 18.0.0 is designed for use with SDK Tools r18. see [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html).

Comment: @duanhong169 I tried to look for SDK 18 in AVD Manager but its all updated already, the last is 15 (at least what I see). Where can I find to update it to 18. Thx

Comment: I mean the SDK Tools, not SDK Platform. Check the SDK Tools in SDK Manager.

Comment: @duanhong169 here is the link of AVD Manager screenshot, so you might see how it is. http://imgur.com/uCUra

Comment: Ah, it's all right.. The Android docs also said `Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6.2) or higher is required for ADT 18.0.0.` If your Eclipse version is higher than 3.6.2, then I don't know what cause the problem, Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not working and you think you tried everything, first blow out your eclipse installation(un-install and re-install).
If removing and re-installing plug-ins doesn't work, rename your `~/.eclipse` folder and start again.
If that doesn't work, delete the .metadata folder in workspace...and start again.
*(you're going to have to re-import all your projects)*

Install Eclipse from repository(I'm using eclipse from software center and the openJDK).
If you're running x64: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch`

**As root** launch eclipse to get the latest platform/PDT updates(they're in /usr somewhere, so you need to be root).
Close eclipse(optionally delete the `/root/.eclipse` folder).

Launch eclipse as non-root.
Install plug-ins.  They'll be in your ~/.eclipse directory.

**If it's already installed**
Remove all the components in Window->Android Manager
Update the plug-in through:
Help->Install Software->Already installed -> Show updates -> Install
Re-install all the components.

**If it's not already installed**
Install the ADT plugin through the Help install software menu.  With [this](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) link.
Choose to install the SDKs during the ADT install.
If any part of installing gives you errors, un-install and install that part.

Install all the updates.
If any part of updating gives you errors, un-install and install that part.

This achieves the results below.
[image: DDMS]
[image: yes it works]
Versions:
[image: version numbers]

Comment: rename my ~/.eclipse folder to what?

Comment: anything else, so you start with a clean one.

Comment: I renamed the .eclipse folder in /home/user directory, however it always creates a new one automatically. Is it correct? But it didnt work. I've deleted the metadata folder, and re-imported the project but not working too. I'm on the ia32-libs part. Nothing yet.

Comment: it's supposed to recreate it, that's the idea

Comment: Yeah, but it recreates without the plugins, I should only copy the plugin folder from the old .eclipse to the new one? Or do I have to reinstall the plugin again?

Comment: Install it again.  If it wasn't working, it was broken.  Don't copy it back.  As of last night when I ran the upgrade, the Documentation part of the 4.0.3 was broken.  That's why it shows as not installed

Comment: Now, when I try to reinstall the plugin after deleting .eclipse folder, it shows an error: Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10512/discussion-between-rogcg-and-aking1012)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it happened after I installed did a mistake at the beginning.
I used 64-bit Linux Ubuntu machine

1. Installed 32-bit eclipse
2. Added platforms and packages following 
   http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html
3. Installed 64 bit eclipse because I had problems with 32 bit eclipse operation.
   But I didn't find that `android-sdk-linux/platform` `tools/adb` is a 32-bit executable.
   Trying to run from terminal it causes weird message: "No such file or directory"

The solution is to remove the step 2 results and start it again with 64 bit eclipse.

I just renamed `android-sdk-linux` and unpacked it again to remove results of step 2.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason this happens is usually the swap space....make sure you have a swap partition and it is of sufficient size
Mine was showing similar problem but it was each time i would clean my project the R would disappear and not come back.
Swap partition solved my aapt problem.