# R.java not being generated in Eclipse (Nothing to do with XML!)

Tags: android, eclipse

So I had to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 recently, and after importing my Android projects back into my Eclipse Workspace, none of their R.java files were being generated.

There were no errors being reported anywhere other than in the src directory, where of course all my references to resources were marked as errors.

At first I thought it was because I had installed OpenJDK, so I removed it and installed Java 7, but it still didn't fix it.

Then, as a test, I created a completely fresh application in my workspace, only to find that the R.java could not be generated...

Does anyone know why this is happening, or more importantly, how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10312256/4294399